# listview data maintain after start new activity

Tags: android, json, listview, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

i have two activty  A and B in my app. i am loading data from api in my listview using json and store that data in listview using getter setter method
in activity A.
now i want to maintain data in listview  after start B activity and when i back from B to A activity i dont wont to download data again from json.

i am right now doing it by sotirng api responce in string and after back from B to A i pass json string to adapter but it still take time to load listview

any idea how to prevent loading time and getting data instantly when i back from B to A.

here is code of my activty A

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
    pref =getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();

    itemCount_database = new ItemCount_database(this);
    item_adding_cart = new Item_adding_cart(this);


    String fromhome =pref.getString("from_product_view_back_Btn","");
    if(fromhome.equals("yes"))
    {
        editor.putString("from_product_view_back_Btn","no");
        editor.commit();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.right_out);
        stored_json();

        recycler_adapter = new Product_list_Recycler_Adapter(this,datalist);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recycler_adapter);
        recycler_adapter.setListener(ProductList_Activity.this);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    }
    else
    {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        jsoncall();
    }

    initialised_actionbar();

    checkout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_checkout_product_list);
    txt_total_amount =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.total_amount_in_checkout_label);
    checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myint = new Intent(ProductList_Activity.this,Cart.class);
            startActivity(myint);
        }
    });
    footer =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer);
    footer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cart_item_count =item_adding_cart.total_product_count(1);
    if(cart_item_count==0 )
    {
        footer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        cart_count_background.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        footer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cart_count_background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    wishlist_item_count = item_adding_cart.getrowcount_wishlist();
    if(wishlist_item_count==0)
    {
```

//            wishlist_count_backround.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
    //        wishlist_count_backround.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);



    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            initialization();
            hidePDialog();
        }
    }, 3000);





    boolean popup_once=pref.getBoolean("total_item_cart_insert_qery",true);
    if(popup_once)
    {
        editor.putBoolean("total_item_cart_insert_qery",false);
        editor.commit();
        item_adding_cart.insert_total_item_in_cart(0);
}
}

 public void jsoncall() {
    final HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("sub_cate_id","24");
    params.put("city_id","3");
    CustomRequest_JsonObject servicelistrequest = new CustomRequest_JsonObject
            (/*Request.Method.POST,*/
                    url,
                    params,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            stored_json_string = response.toString();
                            editor.putString("stored_json_prodcutlist",stored_json_string);
                            editor.commit();

                            try {

                                JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("data");
                                for (int ie = 0; ie < data.length(); ie++) {
                                    JSONObject dataobje = data.getJSONObject(ie);
                                    ModelData_Product_list_act Model = new ModelData_Product_list_act();
                                    Model.setProduct_id(dataobje.getString("product_id"));
                                    Model.setTitle(dataobje.getString("title"));
                                    Model.setImage(dataobje.getString("product_image"));
                                    Model.setWieght(dataobje.getString("weight"));
                                    Model.setLatest_price(dataobje.getString("mrp"));
                                    Model.setDiscount(dataobje.getString("discount"));
                                    Model.setPre_price(dataobje.getString("retail_price"));
                                    Model.setUnit(dataobje.getString("unit"));

                                    datalist.add(Model);
                                    loadlistview();

                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }




                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            hidePDialog();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error : " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
            );

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(servicelistrequest);
}
public void stored_json() {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    String mystored_json = pref.getString("stored_json_prodcutlist","");
    try {
        JSONObject myjsonojb = new JSONObject(mystored_json);
        JSONArray data = myjsonojb.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int ie = 0; ie < data.length(); ie++) {
            JSONObject dataobje = data.getJSONObject(ie);
            ModelData_Product_list_act Model = new ModelData_Product_list_act();
            Model.setProduct_id(dataobje.getString("product_id"));
            Model.setTitle(dataobje.getString("title"));
            Model.setImage(dataobje.getString("product_image"));
            Model.setWieght(dataobje.getString("weight"));
            Model.setLatest_price(dataobje.getString("mrp"));
            Model.setDiscount(dataobje.getString("discount"));
            Model.setPre_price(dataobje.getString("retail_price"));
            Model.setUnit(dataobje.getString("unit"));

            datalist.add(Model);
         //   loadlistview();
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using startActivity use  startActivityForResult(yourIntent,REQ_CODE)

```
Intent startActivity = new Intent(context,ClassName.class);
    startActivityForResult(startActivity,REQ_CODE);
```

after your come back from Activity B ,so can send your list from activity and can get in Activity A.

Then onActivityResult callback method get your intent data

Answer (score 0):

I Have another idea use background task is on create and store it to local db and display the data from local db in on resume .you always call list  view from local db so when you come back b to a on resume will call so it will not call on create so it will not call background data